# Adding rows and columns in MultiDimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have this lab that I cannot seem to figure out how to get the sum of each indivisual row, and column. Here's what I tried:

```
void columnSum(int rows,  int columns ){
int sum=0;
int array[rows][columns];
for (int j=0; j<rows;++j) {
    for (int i=0; i<columns;++i){
        sum+=array[rows][columns];
    }
    printf(" %d",sum);
    sum=0;
}

void rowSum(int rows,  int columns){
int array[rows][columns];
int sum=0;
for (int i=0; i<rows;++i) {
    for (int j=0; j<columns;++j){
        sum+=array[rows][columns];
    }
    printf(" %d",sum);
    sum=0;
}
```

I don't have an array i the argument section because for some reason when I do, my program stops midway. Anyways, please let me know how to solve this part of the lab, and how to format the printing according to the sample run. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's the point in creating `i` and `j` and using `array[rows][columns];` (which is out of bounds)? Use `array[i][j];`

Comment: you will need to pass in an array as an argument, or initialize each `array` in each function. Any other errors aside, each cell of `array` is an indeterminate value, and so `sum` will be as well.

Comment: The arrays are uninitialized; any sum is bogus.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use array[rows][columns] because rows and columns are not changing so you just add the same value over and over again.

```
 for (i=0;i<columns;i++) {
       for (j=0;j<rows;j++) {
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
      }  
    }
          //COLUMNS//
    for (i=0;i<columns;i++) {
        sum=0;
       for (j=0;j<rows;j++) {
        sum+=a[i][j];
      }  
     printf ("columns sum= %d\n",sum);

    }
             //ROWS//
       for (j=0;j<rows;j++) {
        sum=0;
       for (i=0;i<columns;i++) {
        sum+=a[i][j];
       }  
      printf ("rows sum= %d\n",sum);
    }
```